# Multiple date format conversion to single format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column which saves date in a `varchar` format. I can't change it because it is a part of the existing system. I need to convert this to `datetime` because I need to apply the `datediff` function.

The problem is that the dates are in several different formats.

Example:

```
14/09/2013    dd/mm/yy
20-06-2014    dd-mm-yy
1/29/2013     mm/dd/yy
2013-05-30-15.10.04.812055 
8/3/2012 4:22:16 PM     dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy can't make out the difference
```

I thought of switching dd and mm but that will be confusing to identify especially with the 1st 3rd and last case. When I convert as is, it gives me an out of range error. How do I fix this?

I am currently using SQL Server 2008

Comment: You are going to have problems anyway if you have both dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy entries with no way to tell the difference. You should sort out that problem first.

Comment: I can't sort it out because the data is recevied in that format. I know it seems impossible but is there any way at all? Thanks

Comment: No, not without ambiguity regarding months vs. dates when the date is between 1. and 12. in the month.

Comment: Can tell us what date `10/04/2013` represents? Is it in April or October? If we can't work it out, how do you expect to give clear instructions to a computer to do the same?

Comment: Okay. Thanks. i will see what can be done on their side

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. It doesn't make sense to me either. But I am no the one who built the existing appliction that works the way it does.

Comment: If the information is stored sequentially in date order then you could write code to iterate through the records and work out which month you are in (provided you have a starting date)